# JavaScript Form Validate - "False" not working as needed

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, form-submit

I am trying to evaluate a form text/email field to see if there is something there and if so, run it past a regular expression valuation. It worked fine when I included the regex code in the SendEmail function with the rest of the logic  but when I tried to move the regex part out into it's own function(validateEmailAddress), the validation still works but it doesn't seem to want to return false and just stop.  Instead it continues on to the ajax part and sends the email regardless of whether it passes the regex test or not.  It's the same code so I'm not sure why the "return false" doesn't work once the regex piece is moved out into it's own function.

Any thoughts are appreciated and THANK YOU!

```
   function validateEmailAddress(address) {

   filter = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/;
      if (!filter.test(address)) {
      alert(address + ' - Is an invalid email address.');
      return false;
   }
   }

    function SendEmail() {
   var emailFromVal = document.getElementById("EmailFrom").value;
   var emailToVal = document.getElementById("EmailTo").value;

   if (emailFromVal != 0) {
    validateEmailAddress(emailFromVal);
   } else {
    alert("Please provide your email address.");
    return false;       
   }

   if (emailToVal != 0) {
   }
   else {
    alert("Please provide your friend's email address.");
    return false;
   }

   $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/_ajax/emailshare/',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: formCollection,
    success: function (data) {
        ///send that email out 
    }
   });
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing anything with the return value from `validateEmailAddress()`, try this:

```
if (emailFromVal != 0) {
    if(!validateEmailAddress(emailFromVal)){
        return false;
    }
} else {
    alert("Please provide your email address.");
    return false;       
}
```

also, you need to return true from `validateEmailAddress()` when the email is valid:

```
function validateEmailAddress(address) {
    filter = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/;
    if (!filter.test(address)) {
        alert(address + ' - Is an invalid email address.');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You really helped me out!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

`return false;` in `validateEmailAddress` will return just from `validateEmailAddress`, not from the enclosing function (`SendEmail`).

Your options are:

1. Check the return value of `validateEmailAddress` from the enclosing
   function:

   if(!validateEmailAddress(address)) return false;

OR

2. Throw from validateEmailAddress and catch the error from the
   enclosing function (this'll allow the error to propagate up the
   stack to an arbitrary length until you catch it--i.e., you don't
   have to catch just from the enclosing function but also from its
   caller or it's caller's caller, and so on and so forth).

Comment: You were right on, thank you very much!  Really helped me with issue.